# How to apply conditional formatting in google sheets based on a cell being equal to another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a google sheet that I use to track a high school cross country team's race times.  There is a column for each separate race, the rows on the sheet are for each individual runner. So far we have run 6 races, with the results being in columns D through I. Off to the right of the race results column, I have a formula to find the minimum (i.e. best) time that they have run so far this season.  This is in column Q. The formula is `=min(D3:O3)`

I would like to highlight the cells that match the "season best" time cell from column Q for each individual runners race results that are found in columns D through I.  I attempted to do this with conditional formatting, but I can't get it to work properly.  What I want to do is change the fill color to yellow if they match the season best value from column Q.

I have tried to use conditional formatting for the range D3:I26, 
Format cells if: "custom formula is"
Formula: `=Q3`

Answer (score 0):

try simply locking down the column reference with `$` like:

```
=$Q3
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting help from someone else and solved it with the formula

=IF(D3=$Q3, true)

[Screenshot of my google sheet with formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFhZQ.jpg)